# Чистые виртуальные методы

Tags: c++

Как использовать чистые виртуальные методы? Где их обычно используют, в каких случаях, какие особенности?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чистые виртуальные функции делают класс абстрактным. Это дает гарантию того, что метод будет переопределен в одном из классов-наследников, иначе код, в котором выполняется попытка создания экземпляра такого класса, не скомпилируется.

```
struct A {
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B : A {};

struct C : B {
  void f() override {} // переопределение f
};

struct D : C {};

A a; // ошибка: f - чистая виртуальная, A - абстрактный класс
B b; // ошибка: f - чистая виртуальная и не была переопределена, B - абстрактный класс
C c; // ОК: f была переопределена
D d; // ОК: f была переопределена в С
```

Также, чистые виртуальные функции позволяют не писать тело метода, это полезно когда только классы-потомки знают что должен делать метод, тогда в базовом классе можно просто ничего не писать:

```
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue };
struct HasColor {
  // плохо - непонятно почему по умолчанию должен быть именно красный
  // virtual Color get_color() { return Red; } 

  // ок, просто не пишем тело функции
  virtual Color get_color() = 0;
};
```

При этом чистые виртуальные функции могут иметь тело.
Такая функция по-прежнему требует переопределения в наследнике, но в теле функции можно указать какое-то поведение по умолчанию.

```
struct Base {
  virtual void f() = 0;
};
void Base::f() {} // тело чисто виртуальной функции

struct Derived : Base {
  void f() override {
    Base::f(); // вызываем функцию базового класса.
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Их используют в базовых классах для планирования архитектуры потомков. Например мы создаем класс **animal**(животные) и от него будем создавать классы животных в каждом животном будет метод **move**(двигаться), но каждое животное может двигаться на разные дистанции и одинаковая реализация этого метода в базовом классе нас не устроит. Поэтому мы объявляем метод **move** как виртуальный и переопределяем его в классах потомках. Поскольку этот метод виртуальный он лишь создает общий базовый интерфейс для всех подклассов. В будущем это нам поможет делать **приведение типов**.

---

**Обновил ответ.
Пример использования абстрактного интерфейса**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
    virtual void move() = 0; // теперь мы знаем что этот метод будет полностью реализован в потомке
};

class Monkey: public Animal{
public:
    void move() { cout << "I jump!" << endl; } // реализовали
};

class Puma: public Animal{
public:
    void move() { cout << "I run!" << endl; } // реализовали
};

int main(){
    Animal * a; // указатель на базовый класс

    a = new Monkey; // создали дочерний класс обезьяны
    a->move(); // вызвали метод из класса обезьяны
    delete(a);

    a = new Puma; // создали дочерний класс пумы
    a->move();  // вызвали метод из пумы
    delete(a);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, но если можно, реальный пример пожалуйста, так будет еще понятнее для меня.

Comment: смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: А что такое "привидение типов"?

Comment: @kff проанализируйте мой код думаю разберетесь, обратите внимание что используется один общий указатель для создания разных объектов

Comment: Намёк Вы не поняли, скажу прямо. Это не привИдение, а привЕдение.

Comment: а ну понял сейчас поправлю