# Зачем нужен dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, c++11, rtti

```
class A;
class B : public A;

B* b;
A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(b);  // 1
A* a = (A*)b;  // 2
```

Для чего нужен `dynamic_cast`? Какие преимущества имеет запись `1` по сравнению с записью `2` и какие недостатки? В каких случаях какой вариант следует использовать?

Comment: Если программист **действительно знает**, что он делает, то (1) не нужен (лишние буковки).

Comment: Здесь - в приведенной иерархии - ни то, ни другое приведения просто не нужны :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Вообще-то, в том варианте, как вы записали, не нужно приводить ничего, потому что объект производного класса уже ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ объектом базового. Так что можно просто писать

```
A * a = b;
```

А вот если наоборот -

```
B * b = a;
```

начинаются проблемы. Потому что **обычно это говорит о плохом проектировании**. Вы хотите использовать именно потомка там, где используется только предок. Т.е. по сути дописать какое-то хитрое поведение там, где о нем ничего не известно и не должно быть известно.

`dynamic_cast` позволяет не обрушить всю программу потому только, что вы сделали что-то неверно. Ну, например,

```
void func(Base*b)
{
    ((Derived*)b)->derivedfunc();
}
```

Здесь вы вызываете функцию-член, которая есть у `Derived`, но которой нет в `Base`. Но что будет, если вы действительно передадите в функцию указтель на `Base`? Указатель на *другого потомка* `Base`, который ничего об этой функции не знает?

А `dynamic_cast` позволяет по крайней мере убедиться, что происходит именно то, что нужно, т.е. что там **действительно** указатель на `Derived`.

Что до приведения в стиле C - `(A*)b` - то тут, пожалуй, ближе всего `reinterpret_cast` - просто рассматривать биты как имеющие иной тип. Без каких-либо проверок. Что уже опасно, но, по крайней мере, в тексте программы в глаза будет бросаться это длинное слово - `reinterpret_cast` - как указатель на опасность. И это не шутка, это я повторяю Страуструпа - насчет длинных неуклюжих названий `..._cast`.

P.S. Мне нет нужды напоминать, что при использовании `dynamic_cast` требуется наличие виртуальных функций, и пояснять, почему?

Comment: Также использование `dynamic_cast` требует включенного `RTTI` (что, как правило, по умолчанию везде включено).

Comment: Да и это нужно добавить в ответ Harry, т.к. его ответ пометится решением, мне кажется.

Comment: Все же было бы интересно услышать, зачем требуются виртуальные функции?

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487610/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв потому что проверка типа делается проще всего и без лишних расходов - по адресу таблицы виртуальных функций :)

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan: В C++ нет понятия "включения" и "выключения RTTI" - это заморочки какго-то компилятора. И, также, `dynamic_cast` из исходного примера не требует никакого RTTI.

Answer (score 8):

Нет ни одной причины использовать запись типа 2. Она появилась как обеспечение совместимости с приведением типов из С и старых версий С++.

По нынешним нормам НУЖНО использовать dynamic_cast.
Если Вы хотите понять чем отличаются разные варианты cast'ов - дайте знать. Но в данном случае все тривиально. Мы приводим объект класса-потомка к базовому классу

Дополнительно обращу внимание, что cast'ы хороши, что они в принципе укладываются в систему обработки исключений и дают человеческие коды ошибок. А использование c-style приведения - это самый простой ( и не лучший!!! ) способ заткнуть компилятор. И замаскировать ошибку, а потом героически пытаться ее найти и/или исправить

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема записи типа `2`, кроме того, что она пришла от Си? Какие ошибки может породить ее использование?

Comment: В том, что динамик каст проводит проверку соотносятся ли типы (родитель - потомок). А приведение как в Си позволяет вообще привести любой указатель к любому указателю. См. http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/08/c.html?m=1 написано очень доступно

Answer (score 3):

`dyanmic_cast` нужен для того чтобы безопасно выполнить понижающее приведение(от типа базового класса к типу наследника). Например

```
calss Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};
calss A : public Base{};
calss B : public Base{};

void foo(A *a){
    Base *base = a;

    //1 Нормально скомпилируется. 
    //Приведение типа выполнится, но на этапе выполнения 
    //получится какая-то чепуха, причину которой будет 
    //найти ой как непросто
    B *b1 = (B*)base; 

    //2 Полностью идентично 1. 
    //Просто такую запись проще найти при помощи grep 
    //или похожих средств. Так же static_cast не 
    //убирает модификаторы const и volatile, что в 
    //некоторых случая позволит избежать ошибок
    B *b2 = static_cast<B*>(base); 

    //3 Также как и случаях 1 и 2 успешно скомпилируется. 
    //Но b3 будет равен 0. dynamic_cast используя RTTI 
    //определил что произошла попытка приведения к 
    //неправильному типу, и вернул 0.
    B *b3 = dynamic_cast<B*>(base); 

    //Теперь мы можем написать
    if(b3 == 0){
        std::cerr << "что-то пошло не так\n";
    }
    //И быстро локализовать ошибку
}
```

Так же для того чтобы можно было использовать `dynamic_cast` в базовом классе должна быть хотя бы одна виртуальная функция(деструктор вполне подойдет).

Если использовать вместо указателей ссылки, то `dyamic_cast` будет выбрасывать исключение `std::bad_cast`, если происходит неправильное приведение

Comment: Но он вроде же и ссылки приводит, не? Исключение выкинет, если ссылку невозможно привести

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв, ну я ж так и сказал)

_Если использовать вместо указателей ссылки, то dyamic_cast будет выбрасывать исключение std::bad_cast, если происходит неправильное приведение._

Может не очень хорошо выразился, но имел ввиду именно это

Comment: Действительно, не так прочитал. Но тогда стоит добавить, что при работе с указателями при неудаче результатом будет нулевой указатель.

Comment: сказали же ведь - `dynamic_cast` при понижающем приведении базовго класса к потомку вовсе и ненужен, так как неявно приведётся полюбому. Опасности возникают когда делают `upcast` потомка в базовый класс, тут и нужен `dynamic_cast` для избежания неопредлённого поведения

Comment: @ampawd, вы что-то путаете. `Base *base = a;` - повышающее, `B b3* = dynamic_cast<B*>(base);` - понижающее

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb вовсе не путаю, это вы немного недопоняли мой комментарий, под понижающим (downcast) я имел ввиду `Base* base = a` под повышающим (upcast) `B b3* = dynamic_cast<B*>(base);`

Comment: а, нет извиняюсь, это как раз при `downcast` нужен `dynamic_cast` при `upcast` автоматом приведётся к нужному типу