# Что конкретно может пойти не так, при использовании reinterpret_cast для преобразования от базы к потомку?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class A {/*...*/};
class B : public A {/*...*/};

void func(A*const a)
{
    B*const b = reinterpret_cast<B*const>(a);
    b->do_something();
}
```

В одном крупном проекте было найдено несколько подобных мест. Я знаю, что это приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Меня интересуют конкретно следующие вопросы:

1. Если указатель `a` всегда указывает на объект типа `B`, то будут ли у нас проблемы?
2. Если указатель `a` указывает не на объект типа `B`, то что?

Comment: Еще одна проблема: если добавить для `B` еще одного родителя перед `A`, то все сломается...

Comment: Это верно. Если добавить после?

Comment: Тогда вряд ли станет хуже, чем сейчас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Почти наверняка будут. Например когда указатель на `A` получен неявным приведением или `static_cast` указателя на `B`, но эти классы не обладают свойством pointer interchangeable, или когда он получен посредством `reinterpret_cast`, но объекты имеют разные выравнивания.

```
#include <iostream>

class A { int x; };
class B : public A
{
    public: virtual void do_something() { std::cout << "test"; }
};

void func(A*const p_a)
{
    // При reinterpret_cast адрес в указателе не меняется.
    B*const p_b = reinterpret_cast<B*>(p_a);
    // Адрес у указателе неверный, обращение к vtable наверняка приведет к падению.
    ::std::cout << "B *" << static_cast<void *>(p_b) <<std::endl;
    p_b->do_something();
}

int main()
{
    B b{};
    B * p_b{&b};
    ::std::cout << "B *" << static_cast<void *>(p_b) <<std::endl;
   // Адрес подобъекта A отличается от адреса B, из-за наличия vtable.
    A * p_a{p_b};
    ::std::cout << "A *" << static_cast<void *>(p_a) <<std::endl;
    func(p_a);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YNh9Zv

2. Конечно будут: помимо всего вышеперечисленного еще и нарушение strict aliasing.

Comment: `В a нет никакого объекта, в a хранится указатель` - совершенно верно. Это я и имел в виду. Поправил неточное высказывание.

Comment: Что такое `свойство pointer interchangeable`?

Answer (score 4):

1. В этом случае проблем не должно быть (особенно если использовать `B*b=(B*)a`), но как вы это сможете гарантировать?... Чтобы это гарантировать, следует использовать `dynamic_cast` с проверкой результата.
2. Будет задница. Мягко говоря. UB.

P.S. от меня лично - мне *ужасно* не нравится приведение предка к потомку. У меня убежденность, что это говорит о плохом проекте - грубо говоря, когда, чтоб машина поехала, к ней что-то привязывают скотчем :)

P.P.S. Немного о [`dynamic_cast`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547856/195342) - хотя ваш вопрос не о нем, так что если это лишнее - извините..

Comment: Я тоже убежден, что кастование в потомка, - это очень и очень плохо.